# Merge after groupby

Tags: python, merge, pandas

I'm having trouble using pd.merge after groupby. Here's my hypothetical:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
import numpy as np

df1 = DataFrame({'key': [1,1,2,2,3,3],
                 'var11': np.random.randn(6),
                 'var12': np.random.randn(6)})
df2 = DataFrame({'key': [1,2,3],
                 'var21': np.random.randn(3),
                 'var22': np.random.randn(3)})

#group var11 in df1 by key
grouped = df1['var11'].groupby(df1['key'])

# calculate the mean of var11 by key
grouped = grouped.mean()
print grouped
key
1      1.399430
2      0.568216
3     -0.612843
dtype: float64

print grouped.index
Int64Index([1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')

print df2
   key     var21     var22
0    1 -0.381078  0.224325
1    2  0.836719 -0.565498
2    3  0.323412 -1.616901

df2 = pd.merge(df2, grouped, left_on = 'key', right_index = True)
```

At this point, I get IndexError: list index out of range.

When using groupby, the grouping variable ('key' in this example) becomes the index for the resultant series, which is why I specify 'right_index = True'. I've tried other syntax without success. Any advice?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you should just do this:

```
In [140]:

df2 = pd.merge(df2,
               pd.DataFrame(grouped, columns=['mean']),
               left_on='key', 
               right_index=True)
print df2
   key     var21     var22      mean
0    1  0.324476  0.701254  0.400313
1    2 -1.270500  0.055383 -0.293691
2    3  0.804864  0.566747  0.628787

[3 rows x 4 columns]
```

The reason it didn't work is that `grouped` is a `Series` not a `DataFrame`

Comment: That did it. Thank you. I didn't realize pd.merge doesn't work with a Series.