# Merging multidimentional dataframes after groupby and aggregate

Tags: python, pandas, merge, group-by

I am having some trouble merging two dataframes that I created. I had two dataframes (let's call them someframe1 and someframe2) and performed the following operations on both:

```
grouped1 = someframe1.groupby('a_code')

agg_grouped = grouped['acolumn'].agg([np.mean, np.std])
```

Now what I am trying to do is:

```
mergedframe = pd.merge(grouped1, grouped2, how='inner', on='a_code')
```

And am receiving a Key Index error. I'm not sure why since 'a_code' is the first column in both. I'm assuming the error might have something to do with Multiindexing in the grouped1 and grouped2 but I'm not sure.

I looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24397131/merge-after-groupby) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463385/iterating-through-pandas-groupby-and-merging-dataframes) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23587699/groupby-and-aggregate-operation-on-pandas-dataframe), but no one of those seem exactly applicable, or otherwise I'm not understanding them properly. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you `.groupby('a_code')`, then `'a_code'` becomes an index name, no longer a column name, so you can't merge on it with the `on` keyword.

Try this:
`mergedframe = pd.merge(grouped1, grouped2, how='inner', left_index = True, right_index = True)`

Comment: Yes, this worked. It gave me a problem at first because apparently one of them had 1 dimension and the other had 2 (because one had multiple variables that were being aggregated). But I just added another column to aggregate for the one with 1 to change that. Is there a better way to do that without adding unnecessary info?

Comment: I get this warning: UserWarning: merging between different levels can give an unintended result...

Comment: if you post some sample data i can take a look